# Concatenate XML tags to become a dataframe column name

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am currently parsing an XML and from that, fill a dataframe. Suppose we have this toy XML:

```
<A>
  <AA>
      <AAA1 period='march'>ONE</AAA1>
      <AAA2>TWO</AAA2>
      <AAA3>THREE</AAA3>
      <AAA4>
           <B semester='4'>FOUR</B>
           <C>FIVE</C>
           <D>SIX</D>
      </AAA4>
  </AA>
</A>
```

And what I am trying to get is something like : 
`[{A.AA.AAA1.period-march: 'ONE'}, {A.AA.AAA2: 'TWO'}, {A.AA.AAA3: 'THREE'}, {A.AA.AAA4.B.semester-4: 'FOUR'},{A.AA.AAA4.C: 'FIVE'}, {A.AA.AAA4.D: 'SIX'}]` , which would be much easier to work with.

I have already parsed the XML and transformed it into this form: `[{'A: 'empty'}, {'AA': 'empty'}, {'AAA1': 'ONE'}, {'AAA2': 'TWO'},{'AAA3': 'THREE'}, {'AAA4': 'empty'}, {'B': 'FOUR'}, {'C': 'FIVE'}, {'D': 'SIX'}]`, filling the values of the father tags with 'empty' to mark them and then be able to concatenate them following the idea that if it finds and 'empty' value, saves the key to concatenate, and so on.

I would appreciate all the help, guys. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? Please show us your code.

Comment: Is there a typo in the B element? `<B> semester='4'>FOUR</B>` Looks like it should be `<B semester='4'>FOUR</B>`

Comment: Yes, my bad. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is getting the path to the element you are interested in. One way with xslt is to use a recursive call to a template.

The following uses this method to assemble string versions of the dictionaries and hand those to python.

Here's the xslt part, dataframe.xsl:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- match all elements that have text -->
    <xsl:template match="//*[text()]">
        <xsl:text>{'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="pwd" />
        <xsl:text>': "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
        <xsl:text>"}&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- recursive template that prints parent element names -->
    <xsl:template name="pwd">
        <xsl:for-each select="parent::*">
            <xsl:call-template name="pwd" />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::*) > 0">
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('.', name(), '-', .)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To test the xslt transformation with libxml's xsltproc utility:

```sh
xsltproc dataframe.xsl source.xml
{'A.AA.AAA1.period-march': 'ONE'}
{'A.AA.AAA2': 'TWO'}
{'A.AA.AAA3': 'THREE'}
{'A.AA.AAA4.B.semester-4': 'FOUR'}
{'A.AA.AAA4.C': 'FIVE'}
{'A.AA.AAA4.D': 'SIX'}
```

Put it all together in python, dataframe.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ast
from lxml import etree

with open('dataframe.xsl') as stylesheet:
    transform = etree.XSLT(etree.XML(stylesheet.read()))

with open('source.xml') as xml:
    dataframe_str = str(transform(etree.parse(xml))).rstrip('\n')

dataframe_array = list(map(lambda s: ast.literal_eval(s),
    dataframe_str.split('\n')))

print(dataframe_array)
```

Results:

```
./dataframe.py
[{'A.AA.AAA1.period-march': 'ONE'}, {'A.AA.AAA2': 'TWO'}, {'A.AA.AAA3': 'THREE'}, {'A.AA.AAA4.B.semester-4': 'FOUR'}, {'A.AA.AAA4.C': 'FIVE'}, {'A.AA.AAA4.D': 'SIX'}]
```

Comment: Note: I fixed what I saw as a typo in the B element

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked amazing. Now I am facing the following problem in some XMLs after iterate your method all over them. have found that some values have quotes inside, like `<restaurant> L'amour <\restaurant>`, and when I try to parse it to a dictionary it generates an error because of the single quote inside of the value. Is there a way to add double quotes to, preferably, all the values inside the XML so that the error can be avoided and then removed those double quotes after the list of dicts is generated?

Comment: @valware_xyz: please ask a new question. This one has been answered and the answer is accepted.

Comment: I've updated lines 10, 11 and 12 of dataframe.xsl to support single quotes in text() nodes. Double quotes would need to be escaped.