# Remove quotes inside XML text tag

Tags: python, xml

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423635/concatenate-xml-tags-to-become-a-dataframe-column-name) a couple of days ago; and am now facing an issue in some XMLs after iterating through all of them.

I have found that some values have quotes inside, like `<restaurant> L'amour <\restaurant>`, and when I try to parse it into a dictionary it generates an error because of the single quote character inside the value. Is there a way to add double quotes to, preferably, all the values inside the XML so that the error can be avoided and then remove the double quotes after the list of dictionaries is generated?

Or, perhaps there is another approach to this issue? Thank you very much.

**Edit:**
This is an example of the string I am having trouble with:

`s1 = "{'uno': 'l'ebe'}"
ast.literal_eval(mydict(s1))`

Throws the Invalid syntax error.

Comment: please post the error traceback so we can see what error it is raising.

Comment: ```File "<unknown>", line 1
    {'soap:Envelope.soap:Body.ns3:GetReporteOnlineResponse.ns2:ReporteCrediticio.Modulos.Modulo.Data.flag-true.ns3:IndicadorDeConsulta.Entidades.Entidad.Nombre': 'L'amour'}
                                                                                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please post your code as a [mre] - show what you are doing with the data you extract from the XML? In particular, there is no reason for a problem like you show if you have the extracted value stored in a variable and are inserting that into a dictionary, like `mydict[keyfromxml]=somevalue` That will work fine if keyfromxml contains a quote of any type. OTOH if you are constructing a string to initialize a dictionary then you could hit the sort of problem you describe, but it isn’t required to construct a dictionary like that. Show your code.

Comment: I edited my question adding a minimal example that causes trouble to me. The problem is the single quote inside the ```l'ebe``` name

Comment: My point is that you don't need to construct a string representation of a dictionary to evaluate to initialize the dictionary. If you have the values extracted from XML in variable a and you want it stored in a key which is in variable b then you simply write `mydict[b]=a` not `mydict=ast.literal_eval("{'"+a+"':'"+b+"'}")`

Comment: Or write `mydict={b:a}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the value

```
value.replace("'", "\"")
```

Then you can revert that when displaying, or even, you can try replacing the single quote when saving into the dictionary, so its saved scaped.